# Using BC in shell If-statement throws integer expression expected

Tags: performance, shell, raspberry-pi, gpio, bc

i try to setup a little 3bit CPU Meter on my Raspberry Pi2 and after i found out, that the normal Shell doesn't like float, i stumbled across "BC"

After some hours of work i got my script to work, but the CPU usage is quit high because the Console always writes "integer expression expected"

I really don't know how to fix this or why this error even persists, the script works fine, but it hammers my CPU Cycles...

Can you have a look at my Script and maybe explain to my why it throws this error?

```
while :
do
sleep 0.5
var=$(egrep -o '([0-9]{1})\.[0-9]{2}' /proc/loadavg | head -1 )
c005=0.05
c10=1.0
c05=0.5
c006=0.06

if [ "$(echo "if (${var} < ${c005}) 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ] ; then
    gpio write 0 0  
    gpio write 2 0
    gpio write 3 0

elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c10}) 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ] ; then
    gpio write 0 1 
    gpio write 2 1 
    gpio write 3 1

elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c05}) 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ] ; then
    gpio write 0 1 
    gpio write 2 1 
    gpio write 3 0

elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c006}) 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ] ; then
    gpio write 0 1 
    gpio write 2 0 
    gpio write 3 0

else
    gpio write 0 0  
    gpio write 2 0
    gpio write 3 0

fi
done
```

Errors:

```
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 10: [: : integer expression expected
./cpu.proc: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
```

Thanks to anyone who is taking their time to look at this.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gpio mode 0 out;
gpio mode 2 out;
gpio mode 3 out;
while :
do
sleep 1.2
var=$(egrep -o '([0-9]{1})\.[0-9]{2}' /proc/loadavg | head -1 )
c005=0.05
c10=1.0
c05=0.5
c006=0.06

if [ "$(echo "if(${var} < ${c005}) 1" | bc)" == "1" ] ; then
    gpio write 0 0  
    gpio write 2 0
    gpio write 3 0

elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c10}) 1" | bc)" == "1" ] ; then
gpio write 0 1 
gpio write 2 1 
gpio write 3 1
elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c05}) 1" | bc)" == "1" ] ; then
gpio write 0 1 
gpio write 2 1 
gpio write 3 0
elif [ "$(echo "if (${var} > ${c006}) 1" | bc)" == "1" ] ; then
gpio write 0 1 
gpio write 2 0 
gpio write 3 0


else
gpio write 0 0  
gpio write 2 0
gpio write 3 0

fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the if statements succeed you have `bc` printing `1`, but when they fail it prints nothing. bash is complaining that `""` isn't an integer.

```
if [ "$(echo "${var} < ${c005}" | bc)" -eq 1 ] ; then
```

You could pass just the relational expression to `bc`. It will naturally print a `1` or a `0` based on the result of the `<` operator.